# jwt dependency not found in Springboot 2.2.6

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, spring-boot-maven-plugin, jjwt

I'am trying to add jwt in pom.xml but jwt dependency is not available.

Is there anyone who has the same experience?

I'm going to use Jwtbuilder for security settings.

Springboot is 2.2.6 and I'am using Maven.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>co.kr.hatchfly</groupId>
<artifactId>hf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>hf</name>
<description>hatchfly home</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd480.png)

Comment: What error do you get when you run `mvn verify` ?

Comment: using maven central repo or any internal repo?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Thanks. I just got idea after your reply.. I simply did  pom.xml > Maven > Reimport and jwt is available.

Comment: @KumarV Thank you for help.

Comment: after adding the dependency use (ctrl+shift+o -> intellij IDE) or reload the maven project

Answer (score 13):

I was facing something like "dependency io.jsonwebtoken::jjwt:0.9.1 not found" when I added io.jsonwebtoken dependency same with your case.

For me: loading maven dependencies (ctrl+shift+o for intellij idea) solved the problem.